# How do I return a value if a date is X days after a DATE and another Value if a date is X days after a date

Tags: excel-formula

I have a date field "Due Date"

I need to return "AMBER" if ()TODAY is within 1-7 days after the date, and "RED" IF more than 7 days.

- If Due Date = 01/Apr/2020, ()TODAY=03/Apr/2020 , Excel should return "Amber"
- If Due Date = 01/Apr/2020, ()TODAY=13/Apr/2020 , Excel should return "RED"
- ELSE return "Green" because the date will be before the due date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested IF

```
=IF(TODAY()-A1<=0,"Green",IF(TODAY()-A1<=7,"Amber","RED")
```